# Generic List with comparable interface

Tags: java

This is my code. I am getting a run time error when i try to compile it. It gives me an error in the 9th line(contact = (AnyType[]) new Object[MAX_LIST];)

```
public class ArrayBasedSortedList<AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> 
{
     private AnyType[] contact;
     private static int MAX_LIST = 5;
     private int numItems;
     public ArrayBasedSortedList() 
     {
          contact = (AnyType[]) new Object[MAX_LIST];
     }
```

It gives me this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Comparable; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Comparable; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at ArrayBasedSortedList.<init>(ArrayBasedSortedList.java:9)
    at test.main(test.java:5)
```

Comment: What is the ninth line?

Comment: contact = (AnyType[]) new Object[MAX_LIST];

Comment: I don’t think you should cast an object array into more specific types. You can have an object array and protect insertion into it.

Comment: Or better yet, as “effective java” guides: prefer lists over arrays.

Comment: @RoyShahaf It looks like OP is trying to implement their own "list" backed by an array.

Comment: Is `contact = (AnyType[]) new Object[MAX_LIST];` giving you a _warning_ or an _error_?

Comment: *"I am getting a **run time** error when i try to **compile** it"* No, you're getting a **compilation** error while trying to *compile* it. If compilation succeeds, you might get a **run time** error while *running* the code.

Comment: *"I am getting [...] error"* What error are you getting? **Edit** the question and show us.

Comment: @Slaw that may be the case, in which my first comment is still relevant. But if he chose an array to back his comparable list without thinking about it, my 2nd comment stands.

Comment: Sorry if i was not able to specifiy the error properly

Comment: Try changing it to `contact = (ArrayType[]) new Comparable[MAX_LIST];`.

Comment: @Slaw Please post your comment as an answer, so OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

@Slaw Try changing it to

```
contact = (ArrayType[]) new Comparable[MAX_LIST];.
```